# AsyncTask not showing the ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am using an AsyncTask (which I am starting in my main activity) to load some data:

```
Context context = VehicleTabView.this;
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
new LoadingVehicles(context, progressDialog).execute(null, null, null);
```

Here is the AsyncClass:

```
package com.example.schedule_vehicles;

import com.example.utils.VehicleNames;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

    // Showing a ProgressDialog once loading the list of vehicles is completed using an AsyncTask
    public class LoadingVehicles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public LoadingVehicles(Context context, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        this.context = context;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        new VehicleNames(context);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The problem that the ProgressDialog is not showing on the screen.

I type Log.d, to see if the program is going through all the phases - onPreExecute, doInBackground, onPostExecute, and it is going through all the phases and doing the job that I need. **But** the ProgressDialog is not showing. I read a lot of information about this thing and it seems that the PRE and POST execute are started by the main thread, which is blocked by the DOINBACKGROUND method, and this is the reason not to see the ProgressDialog. I tried to find some answer how this is solved - but no success.

If anyone faced this, please share your experience. THANKS a lot!

Comment: Did the program entered 'onPreExecute()' loop, If not try using super.onPreExecute(), it might help.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the ProgressDialog to the Task, just show() it before you start the AsyncTask, not from within the AsyncTask.

Comment: This should not matter. onPreExecute() is suppose to run on UI thread. If he just does this, than his problem will not be that it doesn't close.

Comment: It doesn't metter where I start the ProgressDialog - in both cases the main thread is taking care of this - and the result is the same - no progress dialog is showing ...

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog([Activity Name].this);
```

Let me know if this solves the problem or I'll see in depth.

Comment: The context variable which I use is exactly what you have wrote above - thanks for the hint, but this is not the case :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me. You are correct about your understanding of Asynctask and your use of them also appears correct.
The only thing that I can think of is that you must make sure that you are calling execute() on the UI Thread as well. From the code posted I'm not able to tell what context you are in.

Make sure you can pass in "this" as a context. That will tell you if your on the UI thread or not.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

Comment: The ProgressDialog is created with:
     Context context = VehicleTabView.this;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
Whrere the context is the context of the main activity, so the UI thread. After that I am just creating a new object of the async class and executing. Would you please let me know how to make sure that it is on the UI thread?

Comment: I see how your creating context, you have that in your code. I don't know what VehicleTabView is. I gave an code example on how to check to make sure your running on the UI thread. Clearly you did not try it.......

Comment: Hi Frank,

I see what you are pointing for, but according to me there is no difference between using:
Context context = VehicleTabView.this;
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

and only this:
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

For me they are exactly the same. If I am wrong, would you please let me know why :) - I am really very confused.

Comment: I am trying to simplify the problem. Are you sure those Context's are the same? From here everything besides that looks ok. Perhaps you would benefit from attaching more source code since we are having problems locating the problem then.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing the *context*.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

Comment: As I have wrote above - I am using the CONTEXT to set the dialog. The CONTEXT variable is the one from the main activity, so this is not the problem.

Comment: @ЗдравкоНесторов : Did you solve your problem ? If yes, then please kindly share the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally when creating a ProgressDialog, you use the static method ProgressDialog.show(context, title, message). This will create and show the message and give you back a reference to the dialog.

onPreExecute and onPostExecute are called on the main thread, and are not blocked by the doInBackground, which runs on another thread. onPreExecute is called before doInBackground and onPostExecute is called after.

Here's some example code:

```
public static class InitializeTask extends MyAsyncTask<String, String, Response<Object>> {

    private Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public InitializeTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, null, "Initializing...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response<Object> result) {
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<Object> doInBackground(String... params) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void attach(Activity context) {
        this.activity = context;
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, "Initialize...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void detach() {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        activity = null;
    }
}
```

Attach and detach are my own methods for referencing a cross orientation changes.